# how to select between two separate times of the day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an on-call list where two people are on call for the day. The first person is station in America and the other person is station in Asia to compensate for the time difference.  The America person on-call from 6AM-5:59PM EST and the Asian person is on-call from 6PM-5:59AM EST. Now I have a column in my table called Location (either Asia or America) and another column with the date and one with the name.  Now How can I make a select statement with the correct person that is on-call given the parameters.

PS Normally I could do this on my own, but I have a concussion so I am feeling a bit flighty.

Comment: @Marshal: there is no getutcdate() in Oracle

Comment: "America" or "Asia" is not enough to get the correct time zone. Each continent has several time zones. You should store the date and time in a column defined as `timestamp with time zone`. Then you can convert back and fourth between different time zones and compare the values.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out:

```
DECLARE
  V_TIME date;
BEGIN
    select extract(hour from CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP)) into V_TIME from dual;
    if V_TIME >= '6' and V_TIME < '18'
    then
        --insert America query here
    else
        --insert Asia query here 
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: This is a horrible way to do it. Instead, convert the StartTime and EndTimes to the current date, and split any row in the schedule table having an EndTime less than its StartTime into two rows: one from {time} (inclusive) to 12:00 AM on the next day (exclusive) and one from 12 AM (inclusive) to {EndTime} (inclusive). Comparing if the calculated time is between these Start and End times will yield the result. Oh, and make your end times Exclusive--it's not a good idea to have to mess with date precision when setting up date ranges in a database.

Comment: Never get results by Hook or Crook. Adopt correct solutions and strategies.

Comment: There is no start time and end time, this is a table that serves for multiple on-call schedules which each has its own constraints so to alter the DDL is not really an option and it is part of a larger well put together schema. It is my job to make the application work around it.